# How to convert OpenSSH ED25519 private key to the OpenSSH format that MySQL Workbench uses?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

My OpenSSH ED25519 private key file has the following structure:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

MySQL workbench will not make a connection when the file is in this format the format required is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937244/6694700):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I make this conversion (peferably with a bash command)?
I do not wish to create the key pair again and place the public key in 10's of different places.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Moved to Super User. Unable to delete here, I don't have enough rights.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it cannot be done because ED25519 and RSA are completely different types of keys. You cannot convert between them.

The only solution is to create a new key pair. To create on that works with MySQL use:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 8192
```